# Chrome text rendering issue extra font-weight it seems?

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, font-face

Got a quick query about some text on my slider on a website I'm making. It's been puzzling me because it only happens in Chrome, when the slide loads it will output the Title from wordpress. As the page loads it renders the font as how it should then a split second later it gets more font weight it seems.

I'm wondering what the issue is?

Just check any of the text on the slides in Chrome. Would be great to know why!

Thanks.

[image]

edit* added an image.

Comment: Maybe add a screenshot help others understand the issue

Comment: Yeah, I don't see a problem

Comment: Added an image to explain what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little bit of looking around I found that if I add

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

To my headings it seems to fix my issue. I will mark this as resolved. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

[known issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31833) in Chrome fixed in latest development builds.

It is a [temporary workaround](http://doctype.com/font-showing-bold-only-chromesafari) you can also try.